# A sequence defined in terms of two sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_{n}$, $b_{n}$, be two sequences of positive real numbers such that $b_{n}<  a_{n}$ for all $n\geq 1$, and $a_{n}\leq A$, for some $A>0$ and all $n$. I'm trying to define a new sequence $c_{n}$ in terms of $a_{n}$, $b_{n}$, or both such that

(1) $b_{n}c_{n}\to 0$, and

(2) $a_{n}c_{n}$ does not converges to $0$,

(3)  $a_{n}c_{n}$ is bounded above (by something doesn't converge to 0)

I tried $c_{n}=\frac{(a_{n}+1)(b_{n}+2)}{(a_{n}+2)(b_{n}+1)}$, in this case (1) and (3) are true but (2) is not! Anyone has an idea?

**Edit**:I have a typo! I should write $\{b_{n}\} \subset \{a_{n}\}$, not $b_{n}< a_{n}$
Sorry!!

Also, $a_{n}\to 0$.

Comment: (1) and (2) are a lot to ask if you allow $b_n=a_n$.

Comment: We can ignore this possibility.

Comment: Wfhat can one ignore? $a_n=2b_n$? What else?

Comment: No, just as I said.

Comment: You’re going to have a hard time if $\liminf_n\frac{b_n}{a_n}>0$.

Comment: Oh, I have a typo! I should write $\{b_{n}\} \subset \{a_{n}\}$, not $b_{n}< a_{n}$.

Comment: Andre's question is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

It is not hard to see that $c_n=\frac1{a_n}$ is the best you can do to have conditions (2) and (3) and the best possible chance for (1).

So, either $b_n/a_n$ converges to 0 and you have your sequence, or it doesn't and your sequence does not exist.

Comment: We don't know if $\frac{b_{n}}{a_{n}}$ converges to 0.

Comment: @Nick, that is precisely the point.  You cannot expect to construct this $c_n$ unless you know that $b_n/a_n \to 0$.